# Mysterious AppleScript error: "4.294967323E+9Mahabalipuram" doesn’t understand the “write” message

Tags: applescript

A user of a script of mine which communicates via AppleScript with iPhoto is getting this error, which I can't reproduce: `918:955: execution error: iPhoto got an error: "4.294967323E+9Mahabalipuram" doesn’t understand the “write” message. (-1708)`

The AppleScript that produces the error is:

```
set nul to character id 0
set text item delimiters to nul

set albumsFile to "/Users/[user]/Downloads/blah.blah"
set fp to open for access (POSIX file albumsFile) with write permission

tell application "iPhoto"
    repeat with anAlbum in albums
        if anAlbum's type is regular album then
            set albumName to anAlbum's name
            if albumName is not "Last Import" then
                set albumPhotoIds to (id of every photo of anAlbum) as Unicode text
                if length of albumPhotoIds is greater than 0 then
                    set currentAlbum to anAlbum
                    repeat while currentAlbum's parent exists
                        set currentAlbum to currentAlbum's parent
                        set albumName to currentAlbum's name & " > " & albumName
                    end repeat
                    set albumId to anAlbum's id

                    set albumData to {"", albumId, albumName, ""} as Unicode text
                    write albumData to fp as Unicode text
                    write albumPhotoIds to fp as Unicode text
                    write nul to fp as Unicode text
                end if
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

close access fp
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going wrong here? There's a bit more background in this Github issue: https://github.com/jawj/iphoto-flickr/issues/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work (untested); it comes up typically with this kind of error. But, as adayzone points out, it is probably best to re-structure the script.

```
tell me to write albumData to fp as Unicode text
tell me to write albumPhotoIds to fp as Unicode text
tell me to write nul to fp as Unicode text
```

It's also good to illustrate how tell works (and sometimes "gets in the way")

Comment: Thanks. This does work (or, equivalently, putting the three writes in a 'tell me' block), and was an easier fix than @adayzdone's (plus it doesn't open and close the file in every loop iteration). I am increasingly NOT an AppleScript fan.

Answer (score 0):

Write is from StandardAdditions, not iPhoto, so you can't tell iPhoto to write. It would be something along the lines of:

```
property nul : character id 0
set text item delimiters to nul

set albumsFile to (path to downloads folder as text) & "blah.txt"

tell application "iPhoto"
    repeat with anAlbum in albums
        if anAlbum's type is regular album then
            set albumName to anAlbum's name
            if albumName is not "Last Import" then
                set albumPhotoIds to (id of every photo of anAlbum)

                if length of albumPhotoIds is greater than 0 then
                    set currentAlbum to anAlbum
                    repeat while currentAlbum's parent exists
                        set currentAlbum to currentAlbum's parent
                        set albumName to currentAlbum's name & " > " & albumName
                    end repeat
                    set albumId to anAlbum's id
                    set albumData to {"", albumId, albumName, ""} as Unicode text

                    my writeIt(albumsFile, albumData, albumPhotoIds)
                end if
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

on writeIt(albums_File, album_Data, album_PhotoIds)
    try
        set fp to open for access albums_File with write permission
        write album_Data to fp
        write album_PhotoIds to fp
        write nul to fp
        close access fp
    on error
        try
            close access fp
        end try
    end try
end writeIt
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll see if it helps. The odd thing is that way I had it before works for me and many other users.